# Calling a non-returning JSX function inside of render() in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I got a quick question on calling a function inside of the render method or some potential way to update a method when a user decides to go to the next screen via clicking "Send".

My goal is to change the old created "selectedExchange" to an updated "selectedExchange" as the user taps the "Send" arrow to go to the next screen.

```
// On Send Functionality
onSend = () => {
   const { exchanges } = this.props

   // Testing to see if hard coded values get sought out response
   // Hard code values work
   // this.props.selectExchange updates the selectedExchange
   this.props.selectExchange(exchanges.exchanges[0])

   this.props.navigation.navigate('selectRecipient', { transition: 'slideToLeft' })
   //return ( exchange )
}

// Additional helper method, able to replace the above "this.props.selectExchange()"
// if necessary
updateExchange = (value, exchange) =>  {
   this.props.selectExchange(exchange)
   this.setState({ selectedDisplayName: value })

// Render call
render() {
   const { navigation, account, exchanges } = this.props
   const { selectedExchange } = exchanges
   const { status, symbolPriceTicker, dayChangeTicker } = selectedExchange
   const loading = status === 'pending' && !symbolPriceTicker && !dayChangeTicker
   const avatar = account.profile_img_url ? { uri: account.profile_img_url } : IMAGES.AVATAR

   return (
     <View style={globalStyles.ROOT}>
       <Loading loading={loading} />
       <Image style={globalStyles.backgroundImg} source={IMAGES.BACKGROUND} />
       <TopArea navigation={navigation} avatar={avatar} />
       <ScrollView>
         {
           exchanges.exchanges.length > 0 &&
           exchanges.exchanges.map(exchange => (
             <View style={screenStyles.container}>
               <ServiceInfo
                 account={account}
                 balances={exchange.balances}
                 displayName={exchange.label}
                 symbolPriceTicker={symbolPriceTicker}
                 // onRequest={this.onRequest}
                 onSend={this.onSend}
               />
               ...
               ...
```

What I've tried:

1. Passing an exchange prop via "onSend={this.onSend(exchange)}" to see if I could pass the necessary object that would be used to update selectedExchange.  This didn't work as it required me to return something from onSend.
2. Directly calling the helper method in the JSX between various views. Also didn't work as it required I returned some form of JSX.

Not sure how else I could tackle this.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: `onSend={this.onSend(exchange)}` the problem here is that you need to handle onSend params. Have you tried with `onSend={() => this.onSend(exchange)`?

Comment: So if I understand correctly: you want to change the state of a parent component?

Bear in mind the difference between "props" and normal function parameters. It helps when thinking about these things

A prop is a value bound to a Component
```<MyComponent someProp={somePropsss} />```

while a normal function parameter (as you mention in point 1 "exchange prop") just a function parameter.
```this.onSend(someVariable)```

Comment: @Milore This worked beautifully! Newbie here - why exactly does the "() =>" do the trick? I've spent the last 5 hours trying to figure this out, so I'd love to know why :D. Appreciate your time!

Comment: `onSend` prop and `onSend(exchange)` method had different signature. You couldn't call the second one directly. So the best way to do it is to pass from a new function, which accept `onSend` prop parameters and call `onSend()` method with its custom parameters. Just javascript.